# How to pull out data from eloquent filter in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I need to be able to pull out the category title outside a for each loop but I don't know how to define the variable

I can do it from inside the loop when it's already defined but then I get it on each iteration of the loop which I don't want. My code so far is

```
@extends('layouts.games')

@section('content')

<h1>{{TITLE TO GO HERE}}</h1>
<div class="row saleGames">
  @foreach($allGames as $game)
  <div class="col-3"><img height="50" src="{{$game->image ? $game->image->file : 'http://placehold.it/400x400'}}" class="buytItems"></td><br>Price £10<br><br><button class="btn btn-success">Add to Basket</button></div>
  @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

I need to replace TITLE TO GO HERE with the title from the db but I don't know how to define it for use outside the loop

```
  public function show(Categories $category)
    {
      $allGames = Games::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();      
      return view('games', compact('allGames'));
    }
```

Comment: From where you get the variable `$allGames`? I guess in the controller action so get also the title from the database and send it also to the view as `$title` then print it...

Comment: Can you add the contents of `$allGames` variable to the question

Comment: can you post the method of the controller that render this view ?

Comment: I've added the controller method

Comment: Which title you want to show from the db and from which table ?

Comment: It needs to be the category title from the categories table

Comment: @MattB see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the category in the compact array,

```
public function show(Categories $category)
{
  $allGames = Games::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();      
  return view('games', compact('allGames','category));
}
```

then in your blade

```
<h1>{{ $category->name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to below code:

```
public function show(Categories $category)
    {
      $allGames = Games::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();
      $title = $catgeory->title // this will be name of the field you want to display in your view ;

      return view('games', compact('allGames', 'title'));
    }
```

Then in your blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.games')

@section('content')

<h1>{{$title}}</h1>
<div class="row saleGames">
  @foreach($allGames as $game)
  <div class="col-3"><img height="50" src="{{$game->image ? $game->image->file : 'http://placehold.it/400x400'}}" class="buytItems"></td><br>Price £10<br><br><button class="btn btn-success">Add to Basket</button></div>
  @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```